# C++: Is it possible to use a function of a class from outside?

Tags: c++, class

Is there any way to use a class member function from outside?
As far as I know for this it would be necessary to somehow inject a private component into it.

For example (this is just an example the `notFooClass` function does not compile):

```
class FooClass{
private:
    int i;
public:
    FooClass(int x){
        this->i = x;
    }

    int f(int num){
        return i+num;
    }
};

int notFooClass(int num1, int num2){
    return FooClass(num1)::f(num2); //
}

int main(){
FooClass x(10);

std::cout<<x.f(5)<<std::endl;
std::cout<<notFooClass(10, 5)<<std::endl;

return 0;
```

The output should be:

```
15
15
```

Is it even possible to do something similar?

Comment: *"Typo"*: -> `FooClass(num1).f(num2);` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/b8jonhsqM)

Comment: The program gives the expected output if you replace `FooClass(num1)::f(num2)` with `FooClass(num1).f(num2)`. See [DEMO](https://onlinegdb.com/heHmco9qW)

Comment: "As far as I know for this it would be necessary to somehow inject a private component into it." it is unclear what you mean by that. On the one hand you seem to think too complicated concerning calling public methods, on the other hand it is unclear how calling a public method relates to "inject a private component"

Comment: perhaps you expected that you can call the member function without creating an instance and `FooClass(num1)::f(num2)` was your attempt to do that. Though, you cannot call a non-static method without an instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`public` methods can be called from outside. Thats what they are for.

`notFooClass` creates an instance and calls a member function. Thats basically the same as you do in `main`. The difference is only that you are using an unnamed temporary and wrong syntax:

```
int notFooClass(int num1, int num2){
    return FooClass(num1).f(num2);
}
```

or with a named object to illustrate the similarity to `main`:

```
int notFooClass(int num1, int num2){
    FooClass x(num1);
    return x.f(num2);
}
```